# Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)

Tags: jboss, spring-security

TO acheive SSO, we just need to  modify Jboss Spring security files and placed kerberos setup configuration. 
but we are unable to figure it out why GSS exceptions are occuring.

Kerberos and jboss are running in different machines. Please see the code of spring files, are we did any mistakes in it?

**krb5.conf File**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = LAB.LOCAL
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    permitted_enctypes = RC4-HMAC aes128-cts aes256-cts arcfour-hmac-md5
    default_tgs_enctypes = RC4-HMAC aes128-cts aes256-cts arcfour-hmac-md5
    default_tkt_enctypes = RC4-HMAC aes128-cts aes256-cts arcfour-hmac-md5
[domain_realm] 
.lab.local= LAB.LOCAL
lab.local= LAB.LOCAL
[realms]
  LAB.LOCAL = {
    kdc = 172.18.0.64:88
    default_domain = LAB.LOCAL
  }
```

**Spring-security-07-portal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <!-- Configure security for the web interface. -->
 <sec:http pattern="/**" use-expressions="false" entry-point-ref="spnegoEntryPoint" >
    <!-- This is needed for CSRF protection and must not be removed -->
    <sec:custom-filter ref="csrfChannelProcessingFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
<!-- Added a filter for spnego -->
    <sec:custom-filter ref="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />

    <sec:request-cache ref="appianRequestCache"/>

    <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>

   <!-- <sec:form-login login-page="#{pageUrls.login}" login-processing-url="/auth"
      username-parameter="un" password-parameter="pw"
      authentication-success-handler-ref="appianAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
      authentication-failure-handler-ref="appianAuthenticationFailureHandler"
      authentication-details-source-ref="portalAuthenticationDetailsSource"/> -->

    <sec:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="portalSessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>

    <sec:logout logout-url="#{pageUrls.logout}" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>

   <sec:remember-me services-ref="appianRememberMeServices"/>
  </sec:http>

    <bean id="spnegoEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoEntryPoint" />

  <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="appianRequestCache" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.AppianHttpSessionRequestCache" />

  <!-- These configurations are not yet available through the security namespace,
  so we use a BeanPostProcessor to apply settings required by the Portal environment. -->
  <bean id="appianSpringSecurityBeanPostProcessor" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.BeanPostProcessorForPortalAuth">
    <property name="allowPostOnlyForAuthentication" value="false"/>
    <property name="useForwardForLoginPage" value="true"/>
  </bean>


    <!--These lines have been added to handle SSO with Kerberos -->
    <bean id="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter"> 
        <property name="failureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/> 
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler"> 
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/portal/loginPage.none?" /> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Spring security-03-auth-mgr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Spengo authentication entry point -->

 <bean id="spnegoEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoEntryPoint" />
 <bean id="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
 </bean>


    <!-- Authentication manager configuration, specifying the class(es) responsible for performing the authentication. -->
  <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
  <sec:authentication-provider ref="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProviderWrapped"/>
  </sec:authentication-manager>

<!-- Need to wrap the Authentication Provider using the Authentication Provider Wrapper class. See Appian Forum for details -->
  <bean id="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProviderWrapped" class="com.appiancorp.suiteapi.security.auth.AuthenticationProviderWrapper">
        <constructor-arg ref="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider"/>
     </bean>

  <!--Kerberos Authentication Provider -->
                 <bean id="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider">
                                <property name="ticketValidator" ref="kerberosTicketValidator"/>
                                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="appianUserDetailsServiceNoPwMgmt" />
                </bean>


                <bean id="kerberosTicketValidator" class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator">
                                <property name="servicePrincipal" value="HTTP/user01@lab.local" />
                                <property name="keyTabLocation" value="file:///usr/local/appian/ear/suite.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/conf/appianrdserver.keytab" />
                                <property name="debug" value="true" />
                </bean>   
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig" >
                                <property name="debug" value="true" />
                                <property name="krbConfLocation" value="file:///etc/krb5.conf"/>
                </bean>  
  <bean id="appianAuthenticationProvider" class="com.appiancorp.suiteapi.security.auth.AuthenticationProviderWrapper">
    <constructor-arg ref="appianAuthenticationProviderInternal"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="scsKeyChangeHandlerNoOp"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="appianAuthenticationProviderInternal" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.AppianAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="appianUserDetailsService"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="appianUserDetailsService" class="com.appiancorp.suiteapi.security.auth.AppianUserDetailsService"/>
  <bean id="appianUserDetailsServiceForRememberMe" class="com.appiancorp.suiteapi.security.auth.AppianUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg value="false"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="rememberMeConfiguration" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.rememberme.RememberMeConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg name="enabled" value="false"/>
    <constructor-arg name="tokenValiditySec" value="1209600"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="rememberMeScsHandler" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.rememberme.RememberMeScsHandler">
    <constructor-arg ref="rememberMeConfiguration" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="appianRememberMeServices" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.rememberme.AppianPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <constructor-arg ref="rememberMeConfiguration"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="rememberMeTokenService"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="appianUserDetailsServiceForRememberMe"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="rememberMeTokenRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="rememberMeScsHandler" />
    <constructor-arg ref="portalAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
    <property name="seriesLength" value="32"/>
    <property name="tokenLength" value="32"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="beanPostProcessorForAuthMgr" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.BeanPostProcessorForAuthMgr">
    <property name="authenticationEventPublisher" ref="appianAuthenticationEventPublisher"/>
    <property name="rememberMeConfiguration" ref="rememberMeConfiguration"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="appianAuthenticationEventPublisher" class="com.appiancorp.security.auth.AppianAuthenticationEventPublisher"/>


    <bean id="appianUserDetailsContextMapper" class="com.appiancorp.suiteapi.common.spring.security.BasicUserDetailsContextMapper">
       <constructor-arg ref="appianUserDetailsServiceNoPwMgmt"/>
     </bean>

       <bean id="appianUserDetailsServiceNoPwMgmt" class="com.appiancorp.suiteapi.security.auth.AppianUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg value="false"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

**Server log**

```html
18:03:43,879 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,879 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
18:03:43,879 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,879 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoEntryPoint - Sending back Negotiate Header for request: http://172.18.0.78:8080/suite/designer

18:03:43,912 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,912 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /designer at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
18:03:43,913 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,913 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Received Negotiate Header for request http://172.18.0.78:8080/suite/designer: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAHIXAAAADw==
18:03:43,917 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,917 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using com.appiancorp.suiteapi.security.auth.AuthenticationProviderWrapper
18:03:43,918 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,917 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider - Try to validate Kerberos Token
18:03:43,952 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,951 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] WARN  com.appiancorp.security.auth.AuthenticationEventLoggerListener - Cannot retrieve authentication details. Please update your Spring Security XML configuration, so that com.appiancorp.security.auth.AppianAuthenticationDetailsSource is used as the authenticationDetailsSource. (Expected an instance of com.appiancorp.security.auth.AuthenticationDetails, but got null.)
18:03:43,963 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,961 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] WARN  org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAHIXAAAADw==
18:03:43,964 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull
18:03:43,964 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:69)
18:03:43,964 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:86)
18:03:43,965 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.appiancorp.suiteapi.security.auth.AuthenticationProviderWrapper.authenticate(AuthenticationProviderWrapper.java:86)
18:03:43,965 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
18:03:43,965 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:147)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
18:03:43,973 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
18:03:43,974 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:03:43,974 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
18:03:43,974 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
18:03:43,974 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
18:03:43,974 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67)
18:03:43,974 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  ... 45 more
18:03:43,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
18:03:43,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(GSSHeader.java:97)
18:03:43,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:306)
18:03:43,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
18:03:43,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:146)
18:03:43,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:136)
18:03:43,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  ... 48 more
18:03:43,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,976 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler - Redirecting to /portal/loginPage.none?
18:03:43,977 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 2015-01-06 18:03:43,977 [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/suite/portal/loginPage.none?appian_environment=designer&'
```

Comment: if these files are customized as part of any coomercial tool, please look for a representative from the commercial tool.